# How to remove indexed array using key value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove the array index which contains the key 'parentType' value is COMPONENT. I am having 4 indexed array and in that I have 2 index with key [parentType] => SITE So I need only that indexed array. I need to filter only if the [parentType] => SITE then that array I need it.
**I am having the input array like this:-**

```
$arr = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => SITE
            [name] => PV Meter
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => COMPONENT
            [name] => Inverter-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => SITE
            [name] => Inverter-02
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => COMPONENT
            [name] => Inverter-02
        )
);
```

I have tried with array_diff and unset($array['parentType']) and

```
 foreach($components_id as $value=>$val)
        {   
            echo "<br> Array[".$value."]=".$val;
        }
```

but I did not get the exact solution.

**I need a output like this:-**

```
$arr = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => SITE
            [name] => PV Meter
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [parentType] => SITE
            [name] => Inverter-02
        )
);
```

Comment: Yes you can filter a 2d array by a condition.  This duplicate question should be closed and not answered. I'll wait and see if the community does the right thing.  This is a test.  Low-hanging fruit is forbidden fruit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for remove element by index but it's not recommend because we need to deal with index changing after remove one element.

I suggest to filter result to new array is better.

My method:

- use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- use [class::__invoke](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) as callback

```php
<?php

class MyFilter
{
    public function __construct(
        private array $values
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke(array $result, array $item): array
    {
        if (in_array($item['parentType'], $this->values)) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$in = [
    [
        "parentType" => "SITE",
        "name" => "PV Meter"
    ],
    [
        "parentType" => "COMPONENT",
        "name" => "Inverter-01"
    ],
    [
        "parentType" => "SITE",
        "name" => "Inverter-02"
    ],
    [
        "parentType" => "COMPONENT",
        "name" => "Inverter-02"
    ]
];

$out = array_reduce($in, new MyFilter(['SITE']), []);

print_r($out);
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method to create a new filtered array:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'parentType' => 'SITE',
        'name' => 'PV Meter'
    ],
    [
        'parentType' => 'COMPONENT',
        'name' => 'Inverter-01'
    ],
    [
        'parentType' => 'SITE',
        'name' => 'Inverter-02'
    ],
    [
        'parentType' => 'COMPONENT',
        'name' => 'Inverter-02'
    ]
];

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function ($item) {
    return isset($item['parentType']) && $item['parentType'] === 'SITE';
});
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)